# dc.js - Yearly average values for previous years + monthly for current year

Tags: dc.js

I'm trying to find a way in dc-js to draw a chart that would display monthly values for current year but yearly averages for previous years. Is this possible provided that the date axis is dynamic? I was thinking of grouping records by year before passing them to dc.js but the chart will just leave blank gaps on the x axis.

I would like to achieve the similar result to the attached excel screenshot but on a web-based interactive solution.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an ordinal domain for this purpose.

If you use a time-based scale, then the bars will always be positioned based on a linear mapping of dates to X coordinates. This explains the gaps you are seeing.

Instead, you can define the ordinal domain explicitly:

```
var domain = ["2015 Average", "2016 Average", "2017 Average", "201801", "201802", ...];
chart
    .x(d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(domain))
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
```

You'll also need to change your group key function accordingly:

```
var group = dimension.group(function(d) {
    return d.date.getYear() < 2018 ?
        d.date.getYear() + " Average" :
        d3.timeFormat('%Y%m')(d.date);
});
```

I'm not sure how you intend to calculate the averages, so I won't get into that.

Unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on your purposes) this will change the selection behavior so that instead of a continuous X brush that you can drag, you'll have to click on individual bars in order to select them. There are some ways around that, but they are kind of tricky, so lmk if this is a problem for you.